# How to store a file as blob values using the file service in google cloud

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

With the help of using the Google document [Writing files to a blob store](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview#Writing_Files_to_the_Blobstore)

I can store the file in Google Cloud in below way,

```
 //My servlet Class
  private StorageService storage = new StorageService();
  FileService fileService = FileServiceFactory.getFileService();
  AppEngineFile file = fileService.createNewBlobFile(mime, fileName);
  boolean lock = true;
  FileWriteChannel writeChannel = fileService.openWriteChannel(file, lock);
  byte[] b1 = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
  int readBytes1;
  storage.init(fileName, mime); // Calling my Java Class Here
  while ((readBytes1 = is1.read(b1)) != -1) {
  writeChannel.write(ByteBuffer.wrap(b1, 0, readBytes1));
  storage.storeFile(b1, readBytes1);}
  writeChannel.closeFinally();
```

I have a storage java class to store the data in Google cloud that is below here,

```
//My Storage Class 
  public class StorageService {
  public static final String BUCKET_NAME = "MyBucket";  
  public void init(String fileName, String mime) throws Exception {
  GSFileOptionsBuilder builder = new GSFileOptionsBuilder().setAcl("public_read").setBucket(BUCKET_NAME).setKey(fileName).setMimeType(mime); 
  AppEngineFile writableFile = fileService.createNewGSFile(builder.build());
boolean lock = true;
writeChannel = fileService.openWriteChannel(writableFile, lock);
bos = new BufferedOutputStream(Channels.newOutputStream(writeChannel));
public void storeFile(byte[] b, int readSize) throws Exception { 
 bos.write(b,0,readSize);
bos.flush();
}}
```

From the above reference i can store the file directly in Google cloud. But i need to store those files as blob values using the File service.

Can anyone suggest me an idea.

your help will be appreciated.

Comment: Your life will be a lot easier if you create the file in Google Cloud Storage instead of the BlobStore - https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/googlestorage/overview#Uploading_a_Blob

Comment: ya i understand it i have a doubt related to it can you see this link... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14577801/does-file-service-stores-the-data-as-blob-values-in-google-app-engine-using-java

Comment: What are your doubts? What are you trying to do?

Comment: am trying to store the files as blob values without using the `createUploadURL()` in HTML form. I should upload a file as normal  mutlipart file uploading and i need to store the file as blob values.

Answer (score 0):

Have you add appengine service account into Google API Console Project ?
If you have not done, you should prepare Google API Console Project.

1. Confirm your appengine service account on "Application Settings" tab on GAE Admin Console
2. Create new Project on [Google API Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/). or Open API Console Project for your exists bucket.
3. Make enable "Google Cloud Storage" in "Services" tab.
4. Add appengine service account as team on API Console "Team" tab.